# Image not vertically centering

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have an image vertically and horizontally centered but not having much joy with it.  also I'm needing it to be responsive.[image: picture of text at the top and not centered or responsive] the image is the one in the WelcomeBox div.  The image attached is a picture of the background which can be seen through the divs and the Company name in front if that makes sense.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. thank you

```
    <div id="Header"><!--Start of Header-->

        <div><img id="Logo"src="images/logo.png"></div>

        <div id="NavBar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item  5</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://sermon.net/">Sub</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--End of NavBar-->

    </div><!--End of Header-->

        <div class="firstsection">

            <p>
                First Words<br><br>
                firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection 
                firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection 
                firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection 
                firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection 
                firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection 
                firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection 
                firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection 
                firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection 
                firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection firstsection 
            </p>

        </div>

        <div id="WelcomeBox">

            <div><center><img id="WelcomeImage" src="images/welcome logo.png"></center></div>
        </div>

        <div class="secondsection">

            <p>
                First Words<br><br>
                *secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
                secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection secondsection 
            </p>

        </div>






    </div><!--End of MainContainer-->




 body{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background:url(images/glasgow.jpg);
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat:  no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size:  cover;
            background-color: #999;

 }

 *{
     padding:0px;
     margin:0px;
 }

 #MainContainer{
width:100%;
height:auto;     
 }

 #Header{
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
     position:fixed;
    border:px red solid;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left:0;


 }

 /*Top Logo*/
 #Logo
 {
    width:115px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1;
 }

 /*Navigation ul*/
 #NavBar ul{
     width:100%;
     background:#0f1b43;
     line-height:100px;
     position:fixed;
    border-bottom: 2px yellow solid;
}

 /*Navigation li*/
#NavBar ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    border-right: px silver solid;

}

 #NavBar ul li:last-child{border-left:0px silver solid;}
  #NavBar ul li:first-child{border-right:0px silver solid;}

#NavBar ul:after{content:"";display:block;clear:both}

 /*Navigation a*/
 #NavBar ul li a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:20px;

}

/*Navigation li HOVER*/
 #NavBar ul li:hover{
     background:#8269e0;
     transition:all 0.80s;
 }


/*hide submenu*/
#NavBar ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

/*Show submenu at hover*/
#NavBar ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;


}

/*Make submenu vertical */
#NavBar ul li ul li{
    display: block;
    float:none;
    line-height:50px;

}


.firstsection{
    width:100%;
    min-height:400px;
    margin-top:100px;
    background-color:white;
    color: Black;
}

.secondsection{
    width:100%;
    min-height:auto;
    background-color:white;
    color: Black;
}

.firstsection p {
    width:80%;
    margin: auto;
    display:block;
}

.secondsection p 
{
    width:80%;
    margin: auto;
    display:block;
}


#WelcomeBox{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}


#ImageBoxbox{
    width:100%;
    line-height:300px;
}

#WelcomeImage{

    color:yellow;
    font-size:3em;
}
```

Comment: any chance you have the site live? Also which image I'm a bit confused

Comment: What do you mean vertically centered? If it's `width: 100%;` and in it's on div then it's already as vertically centered as it can be in it's parent div.

@WillDiFruscio I added the OPs code to a fiddle so we can see what was happening. https://jsfiddle.net/tst7sz3z/

Comment: yeah I am still unsure what he wants, flexbox everything and your good to go is my opinion

Comment: **#WelcomeBox** has a fixed height; I assume the OP wants the **#WelcomeImage** absolute centered  (horizontally and vertically) within it.

Comment: yes i need the image centered (horizontally and vertically) within it and the image needs to be responsive if possible , sorry my question was not clear.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to absolute center an image within the **#WelcomeBox** then this should get you moving again.

```css
#WelcomeBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

#WelcomeImage {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="WelcomeBox">
  <img id="WelcomeImage" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make `<div>` centred you may use [flexbox](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) on your CSS.

I'm not sure but if you use `float` and `absolute` position you may got trouble on making rwd site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the previous method, or you can use the `flexbox` trick.

More Info: [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

```css
#WelcomeBox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

#WelcomeImage {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="WelcomeBox">
  <img id="WelcomeImage" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#demo {
    background: url(bg_apple_little.gif) no - repeat center center;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

---

```
<div id="demo">
```